# How-to get network events in a service app?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

On Tizen (wearable), I have to create a *service application* which 99% inactive. However it must get a callback when network of the device changes (i.e. from no connection to LTE).

How can I get this kind of events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the guide below seems to be helpful.
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/connectivity/connection/

> To monitor changes in the connection type, register and define a
> callback:
>
> ```
> connection_set_type_changed_cb(connection, __connection_changed_cb, NULL);
>
> static void
> __connection_changed_cb(connection_type_e type, void* user_data)
> {
>     dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Type changed callback, connection type: %d", type);
> }
> ```

Comment: For this, I'll have to keep the `connection` variable? I.e. I shall NOT call `connection_destroy` on it to make this work?

Comment: You're right. If you call connection_destroy, callback is no longer called because all resources for receiving connection signals are released internally.